# How can I access id and class name under shadow-root

Tags: css

Is there a **CSS-only way** to style a class name or id under shadow-root?

I need to style `id="toolbar"`. I am trying with:

```
#toolbar {
}
```

but no result.

[image: shadow-root]

Comment: Where are you putting this CSS? If you put in the `<style>` tag under the `#shadow-root` it should match...

Comment: can you show me an example please?

Comment: Can you show an example of the issue? It's kind of part of [ask]...